# Seperate concurent remote graphical sessions in Linux

Tags: linux, remote-access

I would like to set up a complete graphical GNU/Linux environment that is secure and remotely (outside the LAN) accessible to many (~10) users at one time. The idea is to provide students with a consistent learning environment from wherever they may be. Has anyone else done something like this? What did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KVM and Proxmox Virtual Environment (VE)](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Main_Page)

Pros:

- Separation of resources
- Granular permissions
- Multiple authentication options
- REST API
- Debian based
- Secure graphical remote access via a VNC applet and HTTPS
- Efficient scaling
- Free and open source
- Paid support subscriptions available
- Can provide access to many different OSes

Cons:

- Multiple VMs may be difficult to manage. This may be mitigated through software like Puppet